# My C++ sorting algorithm for vector

Tags: c++, sorting

As I'm learning c++, I decided to implement my own sorting algorithm. As I'm a beginner I didn't use any template to be able to use them for different types of variable and they can only sort item in a vector. I implemented bubble sort, selection sort, insertion sort, merge sort and quick sort. I'm not asking you to review all my code but you can if you want to, any advice on something that strike you are welcome.
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void display_vector(const std::vector<int>& to_display);

void bubble_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
void bubble_sort_optimized(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
void selection_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
void insertion_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
std::vector<int> merge_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
void quick_sort_rec(std::vector<int>& to_sort, int start, int end);
inline void quick_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort);
int ind_min(const std::vector<int>& v, const int& i);
int partition(std::vector<int>& v, int start, int end);
std::vector<int> merge(std::vector<int>& v1, std::vector<int>& v2);
std::vector<int> get_from_to(std::vector<int>& v, unsigned int start, unsigned int end);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector_to_sort = { -5,2,4,1,8,3,8,9,1,10 };
    std::vector<int> sorted_vector;

    quick_sort(vector_to_sort);

    display_vector(vector_to_sort);
}


void bubble_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    //For the i-iteration we loop the n-(i+1) value and swap if two following value are not sorted
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < to_sort.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < to_sort.size() - i; ++k)
        {
            if (to_sort[k] > to_sort[k + 1])
            {
                int value = to_sort[k];
                to_sort[k] = to_sort[k + 1];
                to_sort[k + 1] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    //Time complexity : O(n^2) where n is the size of the vector in any case
}


void bubble_sort_optimized(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    bool sorted = false;
    while (i < to_sort.size() && !sorted)
    {
        sorted = true;
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < to_sort.size() - i; ++k)
        {

            if (to_sort[k] > to_sort[k + 1])
            {
                int value = to_sort[k];
                to_sort[k] = to_sort[k + 1];
                to_sort[k + 1] = value;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //Time complexity : O(n^2) where n is the size of the vector in the worse case, in the best case O(n)
}



void selection_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    //For the i-iteration we find the index superior or egal to i of the minimal value in the vector and we put it in at the i-place
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < to_sort.size(); ++i)
    {
        int ind_swap = ind_min(to_sort, i);
        int temp = to_sort[i];
        to_sort[i] = to_sort[ind_swap];
        to_sort[ind_swap] = temp;
    }
    //Time complexity : O(n^2) where n is the size of the vector in the worst case, in the best case O(n)
}


void insertion_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    //For the i-iteration we suppose the vector to be sort for the i-1 first value we insert the i-value into the i-1 value to keep it sort
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < to_sort.size(); ++i)
    {
        int value = to_sort[i];
        int k = i;
        while (k > 0 && to_sort[k - 1] > value)
        {
            to_sort[k] = to_sort[k - 1];
            k--;
        }
        to_sort[k] = value;

    }
    //Time complexity : O(n^2) where n is the size of the vector in the worst case, in the best case O(n)
}

int ind_min(const std::vector<int>& v, const int& i)
{
    int min = v[i];
    int ind_min = i;

    for (unsigned int k = i + 1; k < v.size(); ++k)
    {
        if (v[k] < min)
        {
            min = v[k];
            ind_min = k;
        }
    }

    return ind_min;
}



std::vector<int> merge_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    if (to_sort.size() <= 1)
    {
        return to_sort;
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int mid = to_sort.size() / 2;
        std::vector<int> left;
        std::vector<int> right;
        left.reserve(mid);
        right.reserve(to_sort.size() - mid);

        left = get_from_to(to_sort, 0, mid);
        right = get_from_to(to_sort, mid, (unsigned int) to_sort.size());

        left = merge_sort(left);
        right = merge_sort(right);

        return merge(left, right);
    }
    //Time complexity : O(n*ln(n)) where n is the size of the vector
}

std::vector<int> merge(std::vector<int>& v1, std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    unsigned int n1 = v1.size();
    unsigned int n2 = v2.size();
    unsigned int i1 = 0;
    unsigned int i2 = 0;

    std::vector<int> merged;

    while (i1 < n1 and i2 < n2)
    {
        if (v1[i1] < v2[i2])
        {
            merged.push_back(v1[i1]);
            ++i1;
        }
        else
        {
            merged.push_back(v2[i2]);
            ++i2;
        }
    }

    while (i1 < n1)
    {
        merged.push_back(v1[i1]);
        ++i1;
    }
    while (i2 < n2)
    {
        merged.push_back(v2[i2]);
        ++i2;
    }
    return merged;
}

std::vector<int> get_from_to(std::vector<int>& v, unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{

    if (start == end)
    {
        std::cout << "get_from_to ERROR start index = end index";
        return std::vector<int>();
    }
    std::vector<int> extrated;
    extrated.reserve(end - start - 1);
    for (unsigned int k = start; k < end; ++k)
    {
        extrated.push_back(v[k]);
    }
    return extrated;
}


void quick_sort_rec(std::vector<int>& to_sort, int start, int end)
{
    if (start == end)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int p = partition(to_sort, start, end);
        quick_sort_rec(to_sort, start, p);
        quick_sort_rec(to_sort, p + 1, end);
    }
}

inline void quick_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    quick_sort_rec(to_sort, 0, to_sort.size());
}

int partition(std::vector<int>& v, int start, int end)
{
    int value = v[start];
    int p = start;
    for (int k = start + 1; k < end; ++k)
    {
        if (v[k] < value)
        {
            v[p] = v[k];
            v[k] = v[p + 1];
            v[p + 1] = value;
        }
    }
    return p;
}


void display_vector(const std::vector<int>& to_display)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < to_display.size() -1 ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << to_display[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << to_display[to_display.size() - 1] << '\n';
}
```

PS : Forgive my English, I'm French but I will try my best to be able to respond to your advice.

Comment: In English, the letter "I" is capital when used as a first-person pronoun, and "English" and "French" start with a capital letter too, but otherwise I think your English is good enough.

Comment: Just a little correction. Complexity of merge sort is actually `n*ln(n)/ln(2)`. I know you could say that ln(2) Is a constant, thus omitable but log base 2 really conveys the nature of the algorithm much better than natural log.

Comment: @slepic Yes you are right but from a purely mathematical point of view O(n * ln(n)) is equal to O(n * ln(n) / ln(2))

Comment: Yes, im not saying it is wrong. Log with any base could be there actually. But thats exactly why in O notation we usualy write just `log(n)` without specifying the base. `ln(n)` seems to contain explicit base `e` making it seem that `e` is somehow fundamental to the algorithm. Not in mathematical sense, but it may lead to unnecesary confusion for the reader who is not a mathematical machine.

Comment: @slepic Ok ok I will change it. I just more use to ln than log as a mathematic student.

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: O(ln _n_) == O(log₂ _n_); I think most of us are used to seeing ln there, but it makes no sense to introduce constant multipliers in big-O notation.  I think that changing to do so makes it less clear.

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree for the O notation it's what i said and thank i did not know if i should create a new question or edit the existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through the functions and see what can be improved.

## `main`

The `sorted_vector` variable is not used.  Remember to enable compiler
warnings.

You only test the `quick_sort` function.  Consider testing other
functions as well.

## `bubble_sort`

The correct type to index a `std::vector<int>` is
`std::vector<int>::size_type`.  `std::size_t` (defined in header
`<cstddef>`) is also fine, but `unsigned int` is not appropriate.

Instead of looping to `to_sort.size() - i`, why not simply set `i` to
the correct bound?

Use `std::swap` (defined in header `<utility>`) to swap two values
instead of manually introducing a third variable.

In `bubble_sort_optimized`, `i` doesn't increase, so the function does
unnecessary work.

## `selection_sort`

This function can be simplified with `std::iter_swap` (defined in
header `<utility>`) and `std::min_element` (defined in header
`<algorithm>`):

```
void selection_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    for (auto it = to_sort.begin(); it != to_sort.end(); ++it) {
        std::iter_swap(it, std::min_element(it, to_sort.end()));
    }
}
```

The `ind_min` function can be removed.

## `merge_sort`

The function has a strange interface — it mutates the input
vector and returns a new vector.

The `get_from_to` function is also not useful, because `std::vector`
already has the functionality:

```
void merge_sort(std::vector<int>& to_sort)
{
    if (to_sort.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    auto mid = to_sort.begin() + to_sort.size() / 2;
    std::vector left(to_sort.begin(), mid);
    std::vector right(mid, to_sort.end());
    merge_sort(left);
    merge_sort(right);
    std::merge(left.begin(), left.end(), right.begin(), right.end(), to_sort.begin());
}
```

Note that `std::merge` (defined in header `<algorithm>`) does the job
of `merge`.

## `quick_sort`

You are using `int` to index the vector — that's even worse than
`unsigned int`.

You don't have to mark `quick_sort` inline — unless you are
implementing the function in a header, in which case all non-template
functions need to be inline in order to prevent ODR violations.

## `display_vector`

This function has a bug: the function accesses invalid memory if
`to_display` is empty, in which case `to_display.size() - 1` returns
`SIZE_MAX` (which is typically `4294967295` or `18446744073709551615`)
instead of `-1`, since `to_display.size()` is an unsigned value!  The
empty case needs to be handled specially anyway.  For other cases, use
`std::ostream_iterator` (defined in header `<iterator>`):

```
void display_vector(const std::vector<int>& to_display)
{
    if (to_display.empty()) {
       return;
    }
    std::copy(to_display.begin(), to_display().end() - 1,
              std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
    std::cout << to_display.back() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say set i to the correct bound in the bubble sort ?

Comment: @Kiyosuke `for (auto i = to_sort.size(); i--;)`

Comment: Yes why not I don't usually use reverse loop so it will be a good start

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for not using `using namespace std;`.

Enclosing all blocks of code in `{}` is a good practice that I promote, so thank you for that good practice as well.

In C and C++ you don't really need that large block of function declarations at the top if all the functions are in the proper order, but in some cases this is a matter of style, in other cases if 2 functions call each other function prototypes are necessary.

### Missing Header File

To use `and` as the logical AND operator the header file `iso646.h` should be included, otherwise it might be better to use `&&` as the logical AND operator. Not all C++ compilers include this by default.

### Proper Testing of Sort Functions

If you really want to properly test the functions you should have a vector that has the properly sorted values to compare the returned values of the a sort function.

### Not All Functions are Used

This is sometimes a sign that the code is not ready for review or Ready for Use by Others (RFUBO). In this case I believe it is because the testing hasn't really been thought out and only one test will work at a time.

One way to correct this is to not use the input vector as the output. Instead each sort function can return a sorted vector rather than each function being void.

```
std::vector<int> bubble_sort(std::vector<int> to_sort);
std::vector<int>  insertion_sort(std::vector<int> to_sort);

bool vectors_are_equal(std::vector<int> sorted, std::vector<int> control)
{
    if (sorted.size() != control.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < control.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sorted[i] != control[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector_to_sort = { 10, 8, 4, 1, 8, 3, 2, 9, 1, -5 };
    std::vector<int> control = { -5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 9, 10};

    std::vector<int> sorted_vector = bubble_sort(vector_to_sort);
    std::cout << "Bubble Sort Test " << ((vectors_are_equal(sorted_vector, control)) ? "Passed" : "Failed") << "\n";
    display_vector("Bubble Sort", sorted_vector);
    std::cout << "\n";

    sorted_vector.clear();
    sorted_vector = insertion_sort(vector_to_sort);
    std::cout << "Insertion Sort Test " << ((vectors_are_equal(sorted_vector, control)) ? "Passed" : "Failed") << "\n";
    display_vector("Insertion Sort", sorted_vector);

}
```

It might be interesting to add timing to the tests to see what's faster. It might also be interesting to use a random number generator to populate the `vector_to_sort`, and larger ranges of numbers would also be interesting.

Note I've changed the order of some of the values in the `vector_to_sort` so that there are a couple of worst case scenarios.

Much code duplication of testing could be corrected by a function that takes the name and a function pointer of the sort to be tested.

### Inline Functions

The C++ keyword `inline` is obsolete, current optimizing compilers do a much better job of inlining functions as necessary.

Comment: Yes my bad for « and » I’m not yet use to && as I learn python first.

Comment: `<iso646.h>` (or `<ciso646>`) is empty on a conforming implementation - it's only necessary if you want to provide a sop to old/broken compilers.

Comment: @TobySpeight so VS2019 C++ is broken?

Comment: If it doesn't have `and` and `or` keywords, then yes it is, in that respect.  It might be worth mentioning that compiler as a motivation for your recommendation to use the header as a workaround (it wasn't obvious to me why you suggested it, for example).

Comment: @pacmaninbw VS2019 is broken if you don't specify `/permissive-`, yes. With `/permissive-` (enabling standards conformance, set by default for new projects since VS2017 I believe) then `and` and `or` are proper keywords.